# docker-compose and initializating a database

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

I have two docker containers, one Django and one PostgreSQL.  My issue is that when I first run the containers, including the create step, using `docker-compose up [--force-recreate] --build`, the Django instance fails because it cannot connect to the database.  Subsequent use of `docker-compose up` is fine.

It looks to me like the database initialization is not complete before Django is started.  I'm using the common 'environment variables' method to initialize the database.

On a related note, is there a way to get the Django `migrate` done on first docker image creation too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.5.0/wait

To use it, put it in your Docker Compose file, in the CMD section. Like so:

```
CMD /wait && <INSERT THE REST OF YOUR EXECUTION COMMAND>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at that.

Comment: I did take a look and it worked.  Here is what I did.  #1 follow the link and use the `wait` command as described.  #2 use the `CMD` in my Django `Dockerfile` to start Django not the `command` possible in the `docker-compose.yml` because... #3 using `CMD` allows shell chaining so I'm running `/wait && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver...` to wait for my database to be started, then apply migrations if required and finally to start the server.

Comment: Congrats man! Great to hear this worked out for you. This also saved us from a lot of trouble back then.